# ! Undefined control sequence. error when knitting R markdown with \newtcolorbox

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown

I'm trying to figure out how to incorporate a colored box into an R Markdown document. Unfortunately when I try to knit the document to a PDF I continue to get the same Error.

> ! Undefined control sequence.
> l.112 \newtcolorbox
> {mybox}{colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!75!black}

> Error: LaTeX failed to compile box.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for >debugging tips. See box.log for more info.
> Execution halted

Here's my code below.

```
---
title: "box"
output: pdf_document
pdf_document:
  extra_dependencies: ['color', 'framed', 'tcolorbox']
---
\newtcolorbox{mybox}{colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!75!black}

\begin{mybox}
This is my own box.
\end{mybox}
```

I've tried a few versions of this basic idea. I've called the packages
using

```
in_header: 
    - \usepackage{color}
    - \usepackage{framed}
    - \usepackage{tcolorbox}
```

and

```
header_includes: "document.tex"
```

with the packages in the document
as well as including the \newtcolorbox{}{} command in the preamble in all of these scenarios

Here's the .log file:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2022.9.7)  12 SEP 2022 14:55
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**box.tex
(./box.tex
LaTeX2e <2022-06-01> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2022-08-30> (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ar
ticle.cls
Document Class: article 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count185
\c@section=\count186
\c@subsection=\count187
\c@subsubsection=\count188
\c@paragraph=\count189
\c@subparagraph=\count190
\c@figure=\count191
\c@table=\count192
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen138
) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
Package: amsmath 2022/04/08 v2.17n AMS math features
\@mathmargin=\skip49
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
Package: amstext 2021/08/26 v2.01 AMS text
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
\@emptytoks=\toks16
\ex@=\dimen139
)) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty
Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
\pmbraise@=\dimen140
) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty
Package: amsopn 2022/04/08 v2.04 operator names
)
\inf@bad=\count193
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 234.
\uproot@=\count194
\leftroot@=\count195
LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line 399.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \colon on input line 410.
\classnum@=\count196
\DOTSCASE@=\count197
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 496.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line 499.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 620.
\Mathstrutbox@=\box51
\strutbox@=\box52
LaTeX Info: Redefining \big on input line 722.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \Big on input line 723.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \bigg on input line 724.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \Bigg on input line 725.
\big@size=\dimen141
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 743.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 744.
\macc@depth=\count198
LaTeX Info: Redefining \bmod on input line 905.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pmod on input line 910.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \smash on input line 940.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \relbar on input line 970.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \Relbar on input line 971.
\c@MaxMatrixCols=\count199
\dotsspace@=\muskip16
\c@parentequation=\count266
\dspbrk@lvl=\count267
\tag@help=\toks17
\row@=\count268
\column@=\count269
\maxfields@=\count270
\andhelp@=\toks18
\eqnshift@=\dimen142
\alignsep@=\dimen143
\tagshift@=\dimen144
\tagwidth@=\dimen145
\totwidth@=\dimen146
\lineht@=\dimen147
\@envbody=\toks19
\multlinegap=\skip50
\multlinetaggap=\skip51
\mathdisplay@stack=\toks20
LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 2953.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2954.
) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty
Package: amssymb 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty
Package: amsfonts 2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
\symAMSa=\mathgroup4
\symAMSb=\mathgroup5
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \hbar on input line 98.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathfrak' in version `bold'
(Font)                  U/euf/m/n --> U/euf/b/n on input line 106.
)) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/lmodern.sty
Package: lmodern 2015/05/01 v1.6.1 Latin Modern Fonts
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> OT1/lmr/m/n on input line 22.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `letters' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OML/cmm/m/it --> OML/lmm/m/it on input line 23.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `symbols' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OMS/cmsy/m/n --> OMS/lmsy/m/n on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OMX/cmex/m/n --> OMX/lmex/m/n on input line 25.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> OT1/lmr/bx/n on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `letters' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OML/cmm/b/it --> OML/lmm/b/it on input line 27.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `symbols' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OMS/cmsy/b/n --> OMS/lmsy/b/n on input line 28.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OMX/cmex/m/n --> OMX/lmex/m/n on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> OT1/lmr/bx/n on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/m/n --> OT1/lmss/m/n on input line 32.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/it --> OT1/lmr/m/it on input line 33.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> OT1/lmtt/m/n on input line 34.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> OT1/lmr/bx/n on input line 35.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/bx/n --> OT1/lmss/bx/n on input line 36.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/it --> OT1/lmr/bx/it on input line 37.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> OT1/lmtt/m/n on input line 38.
) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty
Package: iftex 2022/02/03 v1.0f TeX engine tests
) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2021/04/29 v2.0v Standard LaTeX package
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for T1+lmr on input line 11
2.
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/t1lmr.fd
File: t1lmr.fd 2015/05/01 v1.6.1 Font defs for Latin Modern
)) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty
Package: inputenc 2021/02/14 v1.3d Input encoding file
\inpenc@prehook=\toks21
\inpenc@posthook=\toks22
) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/textcomp.sty
Package: textcomp 2020/02/02 v2.0n Standard LaTeX package
) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/upquote/upquote.sty
Package: upquote 2012/04/19 v1.3 upright-quote and grave-accent glyphs in verba
tim
) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/microtype.sty
Package: microtype 2022/06/23 v3.0f Micro-typographical refinements (RS)
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2022/05/29 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks23
) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2020/10/05 v2.5k e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count271
)
\MT@toks=\toks24
\MT@tempbox=\box53
\MT@count=\count272
LaTeX Info: Redefining \noprotrusionifhmode on input line 1045.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \leftprotrusion on input line 1046.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \rightprotrusion on input line 1056.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \textls on input line 1234.
\MT@outer@kern=\dimen148
LaTeX Info: Redefining \textmicrotypecontext on input line 1858.
\MT@listname@count=\count273
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/microtype-pdftex.def
File: microtype-pdftex.def 2022/06/23 v3.0f Definitions specific to pdftex (RS)

LaTeX Info: Redefining \lsstyle on input line 900.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \lslig on input line 900.
\MT@outer@space=\skip52
)
Package microtype Info: Loading configuration file microtype.cfg.
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/microtype.cfg
File: microtype.cfg 2022/06/23 v3.0f microtype main configuration file (RS)
)) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/parskip/parskip.sty
Package: parskip 2021-03-14 v2.0h non-zero parskip adjustments
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty
Package: kvoptions 2022-06-15 v3.15 Key value format for package options (HO)
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2020-05-10 v1.25 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty
Package: kvsetkeys 2019/12/15 v1.18 Key value parser (HO)
))) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2022/06/12 v2.14 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 227.
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def
File: pdftex.def 2020/10/05 v1.2a Graphics/color driver for pdftex
) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/mathcolor.ltx)
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1353.
Package xcolor Info: Model `hsb' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1357.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1369.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1371.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1372.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1373.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1374.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1375.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1376.
) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
Package: geometry 2020/01/02 v5.9 Page Geometry
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifvtex.sty
Package: ifvtex 2019/10/25 v1.7 ifvtex legacy package. Use iftex instead.
)
\Gm@cnth=\count274
\Gm@cntv=\count275
\c@Gm@tempcnt=\count276
\Gm@bindingoffset=\dimen149
\Gm@wd@mp=\dimen150
\Gm@odd@mp=\dimen151
\Gm@even@mp=\dimen152
\Gm@layoutwidth=\dimen153
\Gm@layoutheight=\dimen154
\Gm@layouthoffset=\dimen155
\Gm@layoutvoffset=\dimen156
\Gm@dimlist=\toks25
) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fancyvrb/fancyvrb.sty
Package: fancyvrb 2022/06/06 4.5 verbatim text (tvz,hv)
\FV@CodeLineNo=\count277
\FV@InFile=\read2
\FV@TabBox=\box54
\c@FancyVerbLine=\count278
\FV@StepNumber=\count279
\FV@OutFile=\write3
) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/framed/framed.sty
Package: framed 2011/10/22 v 0.96: framed or shaded text with page breaks
\OuterFrameSep=\skip53
\fb@frw=\dimen157
\fb@frh=\dimen158
\FrameRule=\dimen159
\FrameSep=\dimen160
) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2021/09/16 v1.2d Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2022/03/10 v1.4e Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 2021/08/11 v1.11 sin cos tan (DPC)
) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 107.
)
\Gin@req@height=\dimen161
\Gin@req@width=\dimen162
) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/bookmark/bookmark.sty
Package: bookmark 2020-11-06 v1.29 PDF bookmarks (HO)
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
Package: hyperref 2022-06-20 v7.00s Hypertext links for LaTeX
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty
Package: pdftexcmds 2020-06-27 v0.33 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvdefinekeys/kvdefinekeys.sty
Package: kvdefinekeys 2019-12-19 v1.6 Define keys (HO)
) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdfescape/pdfescape.sty
Package: pdfescape 2019/12/09 v1.15 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hycolor/hycolor.sty
Package: hycolor 2020-01-27 v1.10 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/letltxmacro/letltxmacro.sty
Package: letltxmacro 2019/12/03 v1.6 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/auxhook/auxhook.sty
Package: auxhook 2019-12-17 v1.6 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
Package: nameref 2022-05-17 v2.50 Cross-referencing by name of section
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/refcount/refcount.sty
Package: refcount 2019/12/15 v3.6 Data extraction from label references (HO)
) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/gettitlestring/gettitlestring.sty
Package: gettitlestring 2019/12/15 v1.6 Cleanup title references (HO)
)
\c@section@level=\count280
)
\@linkdim=\dimen163
\Hy@linkcounter=\count281
\Hy@pagecounter=\count282
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def
File: pd1enc.def 2022-06-20 v7.00s Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
Now handling font encoding PD1 ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding PD1
) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/intcalc/intcalc.sty
Package: intcalc 2019/12/15 v1.3 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/etexcmds/etexcmds.sty
Package: etexcmds 2019/12/15 v1.7 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
)
\Hy@SavedSpaceFactor=\count283
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/puenc.def
File: puenc.def 2022-06-20 v7.00s Hyperref: PDF Unicode definition (HO)
Now handling font encoding PU ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding PU
)
Package hyperref Info: Option `unicode' set `true' on input line 4045.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 4162.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 4167.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 4170.
Package hyperref Info: Plain pages OFF on input line 4177.
Package hyperref Info: Backreferencing OFF on input line 4182.
Package hyperref Info: Implicit mode ON; LaTeX internals redefined.
Package hyperref Info: Bookmarks ON on input line 4408.
\c@Hy@tempcnt=\count284
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty
\Urlmuskip=\muskip17
Package: url 2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \url on input line 4746.
\XeTeXLinkMargin=\dimen164
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bitset/bitset.sty
Package: bitset 2019/12/09 v1.3 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bigintcalc/bigintcalc.sty
Package: bigintcalc 2019/12/15 v1.5 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO
)
))
\Fld@menulength=\count285
\Field@Width=\dimen165
\Fld@charsize=\dimen166
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 6024.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 6029.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 6032.
Package hyperref Info: backreferencing OFF on input line 6039.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring OFF on input line 6044.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring with OCG OFF on input line 6049.
Package hyperref Info: PDF/A mode OFF on input line 6054.
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atbegshi-ltx.sty
Package: atbegshi-ltx 2021/01/10 v1.0c Emulation of the original atbegshi
package with kernel methods
)
\Hy@abspage=\count286
\c@Item=\count287
\c@Hfootnote=\count288
)
Package hyperref Info: Driver (autodetected): hpdftex.
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hpdftex.def
File: hpdftex.def 2022-06-20 v7.00s Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atveryend-ltx.sty
Package: atveryend-ltx 2020/08/19 v1.0a Emulation of the original atveryend pac
kage
with kernel methods
)
\Fld@listcount=\count289
\c@bookmark@seq@number=\count290
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/rerunfilecheck/rerunfilecheck.sty
Package: rerunfilecheck 2022-07-10 v1.10 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/uniquecounter/uniquecounter.sty
Package: uniquecounter 2019/12/15 v1.4 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
)
Package uniquecounter Info: New unique counter `rerunfilecheck' on input line 2
85.
)
\Hy@SectionHShift=\skip54
) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/bookmark/bkm-pdftex.def
File: bkm-pdftex.def 2020-11-06 v1.29 bookmark driver for pdfTeX (HO)
\BKM@id=\count291
)) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xurl/xurl.sty
Package: xurl 2022/01/09 v 0.10 modify URL breaks
) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def
File: l3backend-pdftex.def 2022-08-30 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count292
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box55
) (./box.aux)
\openout1 = `box.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 109.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 109.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 109.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 109.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 109.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 109.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 109.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 109.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 109.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 109.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 109.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 109.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 109.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 109.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for PD1/pdf/m/n on input line 109.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 109.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for PU/pdf/m/n on input line 109.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 109.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \microtypecontext on input line 109.
Package microtype Info: Applying patch `item' on input line 109.
Package microtype Info: Applying patch `toc' on input line 109.
Package microtype Info: Applying patch `eqnum' on input line 109.
Package microtype Info: Applying patch `footnote' on input line 109.
Package microtype Info: Generating PDF output.
Package microtype Info: Character protrusion enabled (level 2).
Package microtype Info: Using protrusion set `basicmath'.
Package microtype Info: Automatic font expansion enabled (level 2),
(microtype)             stretch: 20, shrink: 20, step: 1, non-selected.
Package microtype Info: Using default expansion set `alltext-nott'.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \showhyphens on input line 109.
Package microtype Info: No adjustment of tracking.
Package microtype Info: No adjustment of interword spacing.
Package microtype Info: No adjustment of character kerning.
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/mt-cmr.cfg
File: mt-cmr.cfg 2013/05/19 v2.2 microtype config. file: Computer Modern Roman 
(RS)
) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count293
\scratchdimen=\dimen167
\scratchbox=\box56
\nofMPsegments=\count294
\nofMParguments=\count295
\everyMPshowfont=\toks26
\MPscratchCnt=\count296
\MPscratchDim=\dimen168
\MPnumerator=\count297
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count298
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks27
) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg/epstopdf-base.sty
Package: epstopdf-base 2020-01-24 v2.11 Base part for package epstopdf
Package epstopdf-base Info: Redefining graphics rule for `.eps' on input line 4
85.
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg
File: epstopdf-sys.cfg 2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Liv
e
))
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
*geometry* verbose mode - [ preamble ] result:
* driver: pdftex
* paper: <default>
* layout: <same size as paper>
* layoutoffset:(h,v)=(0.0pt,0.0pt)
* modes: 
* h-part:(L,W,R)=(72.26999pt, 469.75502pt, 72.26999pt)
* v-part:(T,H,B)=(72.26999pt, 650.43001pt, 72.26999pt)
* \paperwidth=614.295pt
* \paperheight=794.96999pt
* \textwidth=469.75502pt
* \textheight=650.43001pt
* \oddsidemargin=0.0pt
* \evensidemargin=0.0pt
* \topmargin=-37.0pt
* \headheight=12.0pt
* \headsep=25.0pt
* \topskip=10.0pt
* \footskip=30.0pt
* \marginparwidth=65.0pt
* \marginparsep=11.0pt
* \columnsep=10.0pt
* \skip\footins=9.0pt plus 4.0pt minus 2.0pt
* \hoffset=0.0pt
* \voffset=0.0pt
* \mag=1000
* \@twocolumnfalse
* \@twosidefalse
* \@mparswitchfalse
* \@reversemarginfalse
* (1in=72.27pt=25.4mm, 1cm=28.453pt)

Package hyperref Info: Link coloring OFF on input line 109.
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for OT1+lmr on input line 1
11.
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/ot1lmr.fd
File: ot1lmr.fd 2015/05/01 v1.6.1 Font defs for Latin Modern
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for OML+lmm on input line 1
11.
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/omllmm.fd
File: omllmm.fd 2015/05/01 v1.6.1 Font defs for Latin Modern
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for OMS+lmsy on input line 
111.
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/omslmsy.fd
File: omslmsy.fd 2015/05/01 v1.6.1 Font defs for Latin Modern
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for OMX+lmex on input line 
111.
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/omxlmex.fd
File: omxlmex.fd 2015/05/01 v1.6.1 Font defs for Latin Modern
)
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `lmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <12> on input line 111.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `lmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <8> on input line 111.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `lmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <6> on input line 111.
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for U+msa on input line 111
.
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd
File: umsa.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols A
) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/mt-msa.cfg
File: mt-msa.cfg 2006/02/04 v1.1 microtype config. file: AMS symbols (a) (RS)
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for U+msb on input line 111
.
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd
File: umsb.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols B
) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/mt-msb.cfg
File: mt-msb.cfg 2005/06/01 v1.0 microtype config. file: AMS symbols (b) (RS)
)
! Undefined control sequence.
l.112 \newtcolorbox
                   {mybox}{colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!75!black} 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 13597 strings out of 475075
 214898 string characters out of 5783002
 590886 words of memory out of 5000000
 34777 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 491563 words of font info for 59 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 74i,4n,81p,1000b,382s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following hierarchy in the header:

```
---
title: "box"
output: 
  pdf_document:
    extra_dependencies: ['color', 'framed', 'tcolorbox']
---
\newtcolorbox{mybox}{colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!75!black}

\begin{mybox}
This is my own box.
\end{mybox}
```

or with actual latex syntax:

```
---
title: "box"
output: 
  pdf_document
header-includes: 
  - \usepackage{framed}
  - \usepackage{tcolorbox}
---
\newtcolorbox{mybox}{colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!75!black}

\begin{mybox}
This is my own box.
\end{mybox}
```

(no real need to load `color`; tcolorbox will load pgf, which loads xcolor, which in turns automatically loads color. And if that's not enough, rmarkdowns also automatically loads xcolor)